# SQL Server 2008 - multiple import processes simultaneously

Tags: database, performance, sql-server-2008, import

I have a scenario where multiple users will be doing import processes, but all of them will be working for different clients.

I have one core table which gets the most hits whenever import processes run. I have 2 options now

1. To have one core table and do the sequential imports by making queue for the import processes.
2. To have 300 core table, one for each client, it will allow the users to work on the import processes simultaneously without waiting for one another.

Can anyone suggest which one is better and why?

---

I am giving my requirements in more detailed this time. Can you all once again have a look at and provide your comments after going through the requirements.

The query is regarding data modeling for core functionality of my application.

I have a scenario where multiple users will be doing import processes, but all of them will be working for different clients. Also, at the same time client's data could be shown to the user and can be modified/inserted too, while the import process for the same or different client is in process.

I have 2 core tables which get the most hits whenever import processes run.

I have 2 options now
1. To have 2 core tables and do the sequential imports by making queue for the import processes.

Table 1

ID
ClientID
SourceID
Count
AnotherCol1
AnotherCol2
AnotherCol3

Table 2

ID
ClientID
OrderID
Count
AnotherCol4
AnotherCol5
AnotherCol6

1. To have 1000 core table, 2 for each client (I may have maximum 500 clients), it will allow the users to work on the import processes simultaneously without waiting for one another.

More information about the import process:
1. These table is not going to be used in any Reporting.
2. Each import process will insert 20k-30k records (7 columns) in these each table. And there will be around 40-50 such imports in a day.
3. While the import process is going on, data could be retrieved from these tables by some other user and INSERT OR UPDATED too.
4. These are going to be one of the most usable tables in the application.
5. BULK INSERT will be used for insertion.
6. Clustered index is on the Primary Key which is an Identity column.
7. We are considering the table partitioning too.

Can you please suggest which option is better and why?

Also, if you suggest to go with option 2, then would it not be a performance hit to create so many tables in the database? Should we create a separate database for these 1000 tables in this case?

---

I am giving my requirements in more detailed this time. Can you all once again have a look at and provide your comments after going through the requirements.

The query is regarding data modeling for core functionality of my application.

I have a scenario where multiple users will be doing import processes, but all of them will be working for different clients. Also, at the same time client's data could be shown to the user and can be modified/inserted too, while the import process for the same or different client is in process.

I have 2 core tables which get the most hits whenever import processes run.

I have 2 options now
1. To have 2 core tables and do the sequential imports by making queue for the import processes.

Table 1

ID
ClientID
SourceID
Count
AnotherCol1
AnotherCol2
AnotherCol3

Table 2

ID
ClientID
OrderID
Count
AnotherCol4
AnotherCol5
AnotherCol6

1. To have 1000 core table, 2 for each client (I may have maximum 500 clients), it will allow the users to work on the import processes simultaneously without waiting for one another.

More information about the import process:
1. These table is not going to be used in any Reporting.
2. Each import process will insert 20k-30k records (7 columns) in these each table. And there will be around 40-50 such imports in a day.
3. While the import process is going on, data could be retrieved from these tables by some other user and INSERT OR UPDATED too.
4. These are going to be one of the most usable tables in the application.
5. BULK INSERT will be used for insertion.
6. Clustered index is on the Primary Key which is an Identity column.
7. We are considering the table partitioning too.

Can you please suggest which option is better and why?

Also, if you suggest to go with option 2, then would it not be a performance hit to create so many tables in the database? Should we create a separate database for these 1000 tables in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is a third scenario where you have a single table, but you still can do the imports in parallel by having a batch identifier in the table which stops people stepping on each other.

The main problem with having multiple people in the same table is that you cannot do things like TRUNCATE.

For me the decision would be related to about where the data eventually goes.  Is this just a staging table for convenience because there is going to be some SQL for transform or lookup run against it after load?  Would it be possible to make such tables in a separate database or schema and with unique names which would make it easy for them to be cleaned up without interfering with or bloating the transaction log in your primary database>  Do you need to insert in bulk, then apply indexes and eventually drop the table?  Is such a table even necessary if you are using SSIS to load the data, you can often do a lot of work in the pipeline without needing a staging table?

All these things would play into my decision making process on the architecture.

Comment: Cade.. third scenario would be very costly to manage. Moreover, retrieving data from one big table is also going to be costly. Hence, I'll be going with creating separate tables. Now, the question is should these table be in a separate DB OR same DB? Also, there would be SQL for transforming but we can't use SSIS in the import process.

Comment: @user899055 Why would it be costly to manage?  Why is retrieval costly if you have indexes?  Separate DB, because I would have a different recovery model and backup strategy for staging area.

Comment: As there would be around 1 lac records going into single table everyday, which would make the retrieval costlier. It would defintily help, if different tables are taken client wise.

Answer (score 3):

It's not really a question with a definitive answer as each has it's own benefits and drawbacks.

Scenario 1: Central core table

- Pros: Central table, easy global modifications
- Cons: Slower import, more difficult client-level modifications

Scenario 2: 300 core tables

- Pros: Faster imports, easy client customization
- Cons: More difficult to deploy changes against all 300 core tables, reporting which needs to touch all tables will be more complicated and probably slower as well

In the end the answer is whatever really works for you

Comment: David, thanks for the reply. This table is not going to be used in Reporting. Secondly, there are not going to be much changes in this table once it's created. And application responsiveness is crucial in my case. So, i think second option would work for me. Now the question is; will SQL Server handle these 300 tables easily OR will it be too big for SQL Server to handle?

Comment: I've never had any issues with having a lot of tables in a single database before. I manage a few databases with 200+ tables.

Comment: I would consider putting these tables in a separate database (or maybe even multiple databases). And give each client a mapping so they can determine their database/table name without actually having to connect to that database first. This way, if one client starts overwhelming the system, you can move their database easily, and just update the mapping. You can also place them on different files/filegroups/spindles quite easily to distribute I/O more effectively (you can do this with in-database filegroups, but they're much tougher to isolate from other activity, backups, etc).

Comment: Aaron, that seems a good idea. But, how would it behave when data would be retrieved from different databases with joins? how slower would it be comparing with a single database?

Comment: @user899055 In the same SQL Server instance, you shouldn't see any performance differences (unless your execution plans would benefit from cross-database referential integrity making some joins unnecessary, which isn't possible across databases), but you might have some initial security issues with ownership chaining.

Comment: @Cade; so you mean if we DO NOT write queries for checking referential integrity, then there should not be any performance difference. Is that correct?

Comment: @user899055 No, I mean that the optimizer can look at declared referential integrity (foreign keys) and eliminate inner joins you may have in your query if you don't actually use columns from a table (because it knows one and only one row will exist, with an inner join without DRI, the row will have to be looked up to ensure it exists at all and to determine how many there are).  Obviously across databases you lose DRI (the boundary of being able to do DRI is the database), and so that lookup will HAVE to be done.  So performance COULD POSSIBLY be affected.

Comment: @Cade - Cade.. you said.. you would like to go for Separate DB instead of single db, "because I would have a different recovery model and backup strategy for staging area". but there would be no referential integrity if its a separate db and as a result it could affect the performance. So, what you think about that?

Comment: @user899055 I'm just saying it COULD affect performance compared to one database IF you happen to have DRI between the staging tables and other tables (unlikely) AND the optimizer has used that to improve its execution plans because you had redundant joins it could eliminate.  However, you can still largely mitigate that if your queries are properly written (if an INNER join is redundant, then remove it yourself) and tables properly indexed.